# Failed to load component

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, spfx-webparts, gulp

I've been having a problem with Web Parts. I created this webpart and it works perfectly fine in the workbench, but when I tried to deploy it I received this error.

I've tried gulp clean and repackaging everything, but nothing seems to help.

I trused the certificate with gulp. Do I have to do this on the sharepoint itself too?

```
[SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]:
***Failed to load component "77a46a33-41c2-42c4-a014-95198e8b8f94" (RisksWebPart). Original error: ***Failed to load URL 'https://publiccdn.sharepointonline.com/icontiocr.sharepoint.com/sites/appcatalog/ClientSideAssets/0b94c254-49e2-419e-b106-3bf413792221/risks-webpart-riskswebpartstrings_en-us_536e65149b0acf4d52c0043073b9fc59.js' for resource 'RisksWebPartStrings' in component '77a46a33-41c2-42c4-a014-95198e8b8f94' (RisksWebPart). There was a network problem. This may be a problem with a HTTPS certificate. Make sure you have the right certificate.

***INNERERROR:
***Failed to load URL 'https://publiccdn.sharepointonline.com/icontiocr.sharepoint.com/sites/appcatalog/ClientSideAssets/0b94c254-49e2-419e-b106-3bf413792221/risks-webpart-riskswebpartstrings_en-us_536e65149b0acf4d52c0043073b9fc59.js' for resource 'RisksWebPartStrings' in component '77a46a33-41c2-42c4-a014-95198e8b8f94' (RisksWebPart). There was a network problem. This may be a problem with a HTTPS certificate. Make sure you have the right certificate.
***CALLSTACK:
t@https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-classic-page-assembly_en-us_9fb528d59bd0785aa343b5cb10705a8a.js:3:53489
t@https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-classic-page-assembly_en-us_9fb528d59bd0785aa343b5cb10705a8a.js:18:103217
jx2P/s</e.buildErrorWithVerboseLog@https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-classic-page-assembly_en-us_9fb528d59bd0785aa343b5cb10705a8a.js:18:113177
jx2P/s</e.buildLoadComponentError@https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-classic-page-assembly_en-us_9fb528d59bd0785aa343b5cb10705a8a.js:18:109208
e/</<@https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-classic-page-assembly_en-us_9fb528d59bd0785aa343b5cb10705a8a.js:18:99369
promise callback*e/<@https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-classic-page-assembly_en-us_9fb528d59bd0785aa343b5cb10705a8a.js:18:99340
e@https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-classic-page-assembly_en-us_9fb528d59bd0785aa343b5cb10705a8a.js:18:99401
e/<@https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-classic-page-assembly_en-us_9fb528d59bd0785aa343b5cb10705a8a.js:18:99573
promise callback*e@https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-classic-page-assembly_en-us_9fb528d59bd0785aa343b5cb10705a8a.js:18:99528
e/<@https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-classic-page-assembly_en-us_9fb528d59bd0785aa343b5cb10705a8a.js:18:99573
promise callback*e@https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-classic-page-assembly_en-us_9fb528d59bd0785aa343b5cb10705a8a.js:18:99528
h@https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-classic-page-assembly_en-us_9fb528d59bd0785aa343b5cb10705a8a.js:18:99700
yJ2x/g</t.prototype.loadComponent@https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-classic-page-assembly_en-us_9fb528d59bd0785aa343b5cb10705a8a.js:18:149841
kUqz/o</e.loadComponent@https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-classic-page-assembly_en-us_9fb528d59bd0785aa343b5cb10705a8a.js:18:113887
DCnD/le</e.prototype._loadWebPartModules@https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-classic-page-assembly_en-us_9fb528d59bd0785aa343b5cb10705a8a.js:21:176430
DCnD/le</e.prototype.loadWebPart/s<@https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-classic-page-assembly_en-us_9fb528d59bd0785aa343b5cb10705a8a.js:21:165149
DCnD/le</e.prototype.loadWebPart@https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-classic-page-assembly_en-us_9fb528d59bd0785aa343b5cb10705a8a.js:21:163069
dacX/f</t.prototype.loadWebPart@https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-classic-page-assembly_en-us_9fb528d59bd0785aa343b5cb10705a8a.js:1:41477
@https://icontiocr.sharepoint.com/sites/Develop/arnetest/Lists/Assets/NewForm.aspx?Source=https%3a%2f%2ficontiocr.sharepoint.com%2fsites%2fDevelop%2farnetest%2fLists%2fAssets%2fAllItems.aspx&RootFolder=%2fsites%2fDevelop%2farnetest%2fLists%2fAssets&PageView=Shared&InitialTabId=Ribbon.WebPartPage&VisibilityContext=WSSWebPartPage:734:37
```

Comment: Is it working in IE browser? On which browser are you trying now?

Comment: I am using mozilla firefox, but I tried IE and it also doesn't work there.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.koskila.net/failed-to-load-component-original-error-failed-to-load-path-dependency-contosospfxwebpartlocalization-from-component-guid-contosospfxwebpart/) and [this](https://sharepains.com/2017/05/09/office-365-sharepoint-spfx-there-was-a-network-problem-this-may-be-a-problem-with-a-https-certificate-make-sure-you-have-the-right-certificate/). let me know if anything helps you.

Comment: I have tried these. I did find out I can't access the CDN from anywhere. I don't even know what URL it's supposed to be as I am using a subsite as well. Anything I try gives me an access denied page.

Comment: If you don't want to host your webpart from CDN then try setting `includeClientSideAssets` to `true` in `package-solution.json` from the `config` folder. Then again build and package your solution and re-upload on app catalog.

Comment: It is set to true... I still get this error.

Comment: What is set to `cdnBasePath` property in `write-manifests.json` file??

Comment: ```<!-- PATH TO CDN -->```

Comment: @GaneshSanap I just don't understand why it still uses the CDN when I don't have it set anywhere in my config. Am I doing something wrong with the deployment where I'm not using the web part that I just deployed and instead is using an old version? I'm just so confused I don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the version of your solution within package-solution.json to force an update when deployed, rebuild, generate a new package and deploy again.
I had had an annoying experience before where the solution seen to not update until I increased the version....
Not sure if it will resolve your problem, but it's worth the try as it only take a few minutes